# how long before a process receives a socket closed message

Tags: ssl, erlang, gen-tcp

Suppose you have an Erlang process which is handling a socket (gen_tcp/ssl) and the peer closes the connection.

How long does it take before the process receives a message like:

```
{tcp_closed, Socket}
```

or

```
{ssl_closed, Socket}
```

Is this amount of time specified somewhere in Erlang code or is it related to the system?

Comment: graceful close of the socket or an machine crashing? for the later it takes as long as your operating system says, for the first EJP answered it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should take one ping time of the network, unless congestion is present.